# Dynamic SQL date alising for columns and ordering

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a select query report like this

```
EmpID Title M1 M2 M3 M4 M5 M6 M7 M8 M9 M10 M11 M12
1      PM  
2      BA   
3      QA
```

`EmpID` and `Title` are coming from the `Emp` table and all the `M1` to `M12` are coming from `Code` table

`M1` is always January, `M2` is always February ...`M12` always December etc

If I execute this query on May 1 2017, I will have to get

```
EmpID Title  2016-05-1 2016-06-1 2016-07-1 2016-08-1 2016-09-1 2016-010-1 2016-11-1 2016-12-1 2017-01-1 2017-02-1 2017-03-1 2017-04-1 
1     PM  
2     BA    
3     QA
```

That means,

```
EmpID Title  M5 M6 M7 M8 M9 M10 M11 M12 M1 M2 M3 M4
1     PM  
2     BA    
3     QA
```

If I execute this query on June 1 2017, I will have to get

```
EmpID Title   2016-06-1 2016-07-1 2016-08-1 2016-09-1 2016-010-1 2016-11-1 2016-12-1 2017-01-1 2017-02-1 2017-03-1 2017-04-1 2017-05-1
1     PM  
2     BA    
3     QA
```

That means:

```
EmpID Title  M6 M7 M8 M9 M10 M11 M12 M1 M2 M3 M4 M5
1     PM  
2     BA    
3     QA
```

I have created a temporary table and drop all the required month into that

```
Select * 
Into #TempDates 
From
    (Select  
         MyDate = convert(date, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)) 
     union all----Current month-1 
     Select x2 = convert(date, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 1, GETDATE()) - 2, 0)) 
     union all----Current month-2
     Select x3 = convert(date, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 2, GETDATE()) - 3, 0)) 
     union all--Current month-3
     Select x4 = convert(date, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 2, GETDATE()) - 4, 0)) 
     union all--Current month-4
select x5=convert(date,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 2, GETDATE())-5, 0) ) union all--Current month-5
select x6=convert(date,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 2, GETDATE())-6, 0) ) union all--Current month-6
select x7=convert(date,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 2, GETDATE())-7, 0) ) union all--Current month-7
select x8=convert(date,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 2, GETDATE())-8, 0) ) union all--Current month-8
select x9=convert(date,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 2, GETDATE())-9, 0) ) union all--Current month-9
select x10=convert(date,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 2, GETDATE())-10, 0) ) union all--Current month-10
select x11=convert(date,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 2, GETDATE())-11, 0) ) union all--Current month-11
select x12=convert(date,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 2, GETDATE())-12, 0) )--Current month-12
) AS X
```

I wanted a report like this :

```
Select 
    Emp.EmpID as 'Employee ID',
    Emp.Title as 'Employee Title',
    Code.M1 as (Select Mydate from #TempDates where datepart(month, Mydate) = 1),
    Code.M2 as (Select Mydate from #TempDates where datepart(month, Mydate) = 2),
    Code.M3 as (Select Mydate from #TempDates where datepart(month, Mydate) = 3)  
    .
    .
    .
    Code.M12 as (Select Mydate from #TempDates where datepart(month, Mydate) = 12)
From 
    Emp 
Join 
    Code on Emp.ID = Code.ID
Order by 
    Mydate asc
```

Could anyone please help me do this? I do not know how to alias the date with column names. I am using SQL Server 2014.

Thank you very much for taking time to read my question and thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

First, I generate the dates tables on this way:

> ```
> SELECT  X, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MyDate,101) MyDate INTO #dates
> FROM (SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, mth.x, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) MyDate, mth.x + 1 as X 
>       FROM (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11)) mth(x)) M;
> ```

It produces the next result:

> ```
> SELECT * FROM #dates;
> ```
>
> ```
>    X | MyDate
>
>   -: | :---------
>    1 | 05/03/2017
>    2 | 06/03/2017
>    3 | 07/03/2017
>    4 | 08/03/2017
>    5 | 09/03/2017
>    6 | 10/03/2017
>    7 | 11/03/2017
>    8 | 12/03/2017
>    9 | 01/03/2018
>   10 | 02/03/2018
>   11 | 03/03/2018
>   12 | 04/03/2018
> ```

Now, I've set up a reduced example:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE #Emp(EmpID int, Title varchar(10));
> INSERT INTO #Emp VALUES (1,'PM'),(2,'BA'),(3,'QA');
> CREATE TABLE #Code(ID int, M1 int, M2 int, M3 int, M4 int, M5 int, M6 int, M7 int, M8 int, M9 int, M10 int, M11 int, M12 int);
> INSERT INTO #Code VALUES
> (1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12),
> (2, 11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 81, 91, 101, 111, 121),
> (3, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 210, 211, 212);
>
> DECLARE @rows nvarchar(max);
> SET @rows = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + ('M' + CAST(X as varchar(10)) + ' AS ' + QUOTENAME(MyDate)) 
>                   FROM (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT X, MyDate FROM #dates ORDER BY X) t
>             FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
>             ).value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)') 
>            ,1,1,'');
>
> DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(max);
> SET @cmd = 'SELECT EmpID, Title, ' + @rows + ' FROM #Emp INNER JOIN #Code ON #Emp.EmpID = #Code.ID';
> SELECT @cmd;
>
> EXEC (@cmd);
> GO
> ```

This is the generated query:

```
SELECT EmpID, 
       Title, 
       M1 AS [05/03/2017],
       M2 AS [06/03/2017],
       M3 AS [07/03/2017],
       M4 AS [08/03/2017],
       M5 AS [09/03/2017],
       M6 AS [10/03/2017],
       M7 AS [11/03/2017],
       M8 AS [12/03/2017],
       M9 AS [01/03/2018],
       M10 AS [02/03/2018],
       M11 AS [03/03/2018],
       M12 AS [04/03/2018] 
FROM #Emp 
INNER JOIN #Code 
ON #Emp.EmpID = #Code.ID
```

> ```
> EmpID | Title | 05/03/2017 | 06/03/2017 | 07/03/2017 | 08/03/2017 | 09/03/2017 | 10/03/2017 | 11/03/2017 | 12/03/2017 | 01/03/2018 | 02/03/2018 | 03/03/2018 | 04/03/2018
> ----: | :---- | ---------: | ---------: | ---------: | ---------: | ---------: | ---------: | ---------: | ---------: | ---------: | ---------: | ---------: | ---------:
>     1 | PM    |          1 |          2 |          3 |          4 |          5 |          6 |          7 |          8 |          9 |         10 |         11 |         12
>     2 | BA    |         11 |         21 |         31 |         41 |         51 |         61 |         71 |         81 |         91 |        101 |        111 |        121
>     3 | QA    |         21 |         22 |         23 |         24 |         25 |         26 |         27 |         28 |         29 |        210 |        211 |        212
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=c7b4e09f536299f20d24ee55abdedd57)*

Comment: Thank you very much McNets for your great help. I will try this and let you know